# When will the newest Magento 1.9.1 release?

Tags: version

Does anyone know when the new version CE 1.9.1 is released? 
I will hire a Magento web developer to update my website from version CE 1.4.0.1 to 1.9.1 but I need to know when the new one is released?
Can I update the PayPal Checkout from SSL 3.0 to TSL on my current Magento website 1.4.0.1 and how?

Comment: This is not really a stack exchange question but rather a question related to the release of the Magento product which Magento can only answer

Comment: Why don't you go with 1.9.0.1?

Answer (score 1):

Release will be very soon, we are finalizing just few last details. 
You should update PayPal if this is needed and updating your servers as well (if needed) as soon as possible.

Note that I would suggest to wait with launching the upgrade after Christmas season as it brings many changes - including responsive theme that need to be implemented in your theme and your customizations.